# How to add dynamic jsf content (in a string) to JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Usually we use ui:include to add test.xhtml to main.xhtml - 
in main.xhtml

```
    <ui:include src="/test.xhtml" />
```

instead of test.xhtml, If we have jsf content as String, how do we include in main.xhtml

your help in this regard, greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Ravi

Comment: you want include the page content is that correct ?!?

Comment: It is interesting solution, but creating a File for every request even with the caching may work for limited number of dynamic requests. But if the dynamic requests are in millions, this solution can not be scalable.